# Importing data from column of one data frame to another dataframe in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe1 of x*y dimensions. I need to import some of the columns in an empty dataframe2 having 0*z dimensions. Running command

```
 dataframe2$z1 <- dataframe1$y1
```

gives this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "y1", value = c(140100303L,  : 
  replacement has x rows, data has 1
```

Using the append command also ends with similar error.

Comment: Why don't you create `dataframe2` directly from `dataframe1`?

Comment: in addition to pascal comment, try to search and learn data.frame subsetting in R.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dataframe1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, ncol=2))
```

Suppose, you wanted to select one column "V1" from `dataframe1`
and create a new `data.frame`

```
 dataframe2 <- setNames(dataframe1[,"V1",drop=F],"z1")
```

Or if you know the dimensions of dataframe1 before, create dataframe2 with the same row size.

```
dataframe2 <- data.frame(Z1=numeric(nrow(dataframe1)), Z2=numeric(nrow(dataframe1)))
dataframe2$Z1 <- dataframe1$V1 #works
```